# aspnetcore development time iis file locking

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, asp.net-core, iis-express

When I start IIS or IIS express without debugging then make a change then build, I get a file lock error so the build fails. This is because IIS(/express) locks the dll files in the bin folder.

In visual studio 2015 with regular aspnet, we were able to build even if the website is up and running without any locking issue.

Is there a way to configure IIS os IIS Express to not lock files so that we can rebuild without having to kill the dotnet or iis express process?

PS: I have recently added development time IIS support to visual studio 2017, but found out that it suffers the same (file locking) issue as IIS express development time.

Thank you,

Comment: It is April 2020 and on the verge of .Net 5.0 we still have this issue! So annoying